# Users of android app are not showing up in Firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication

I made an android app and in that I just created login and registration page using firebase but when I sign up with a new account then that respective account should be recorded or it should be displayed in the user section of my Firebase But in the user section "No users are added yet" this message is displayed. Why is it so?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.easylearn">

 <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
  <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
  package com.example.easylearn;
  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText emailId,password;
  Button btnSignUp;
  TextView tvSignIn;
  FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  emailId = findViewById(R.id.editText);
  password = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.button2);
  tvSignIn = findViewById(R.id.textView);
  btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  String email = emailId.getText().toString();
  String pwd = password.getText().toString();
  if(email.isEmpty())
  {
  emailId.setError("Please enter email id");
  emailId.requestFocus();
  }
  else if(pwd.isEmpty())
  {
  password.setError("Please enter password");
  password.requestFocus();
  }
  else if(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())
  {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Fiels are Empty!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else if(!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()))
  {
  mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this,
  new OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult> task) 
  {
  if(task.isSuccessful())
  {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"SignUp Unsuccessful,Please Try 
  Again..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else {
  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
  }
  }
  });
  }
  else
  {
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error Occured!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
  });
  tvSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
  }
  });
  }
  }
```

This is my LoginActivity.java

```
  package com.example.easylearn;

  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
  import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText emailId,password;
  Button btnSignIn;
  TextView tvSignUp;
  FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
  private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  emailId = findViewById(R.id.editText);
  password = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  btnSignIn = findViewById(R.id.button2);
  tvSignUp = findViewById(R.id.textView);

  mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
  FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
  if(mFirebaseUser != null){
  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"You are logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
  }
  else{
  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please login",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
  };

  btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  String email = emailId.getText().toString();
  String pwd = password.getText().toString();
  if(email.isEmpty())
  {
  emailId.setError("Please enter email id");
  emailId.requestFocus();
  }
  else if(pwd.isEmpty())
  {
  password.setError("Please enter password");
  password.requestFocus();
  }
  else if(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty())
  {
  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Fiels are Empty!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else if(!(email.isEmpty() && pwd.isEmpty()))
  {

  mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new 
  OnCompleteListener<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult> task) 
  {
  if(!task.isSuccessful()){
  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Login Error,Please Login      
  again..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  else{
  Intent inToHome = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
  startActivity(inToHome);
  }
  }
  });
  }
  else
  {
  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error Occured!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
  });

  tvSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intSignUp = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intSignUp);
  }
  });
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
  }
  }`
```